# Has there been any nuclear thermal rocket test program after NERVA?

Tags: rockets, nuclear, ntr

Has NASA tested any nuclear thermal rocket engine after dropping the NERVA program? Is there any current ongoing mission to use nuclear power to make a rocket fly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of 2012 (Nuclear and Emerging Technologies in Space meeting at LPI) the outline of development program is as [follows](http://www.lpi.usra.edu/meetings/nets2012/pdf/3088.pdf):

**See [this pdf file](http://www.lpi.usra.edu/meetings/nets2012/pdf/program.pdf) for links to papers.**

(note: only tangible test & evaluation items listed)

- Manufacture and test fuel elements in two compositions: NERVA composite, and Uranium dioxide UO2 in tungsten ceramic-metallic "cermet". Testing will be conducted at DOE facilities and at Marshall (NTR Element Environmental Simulator)
- Conduct safety tests at Nevada Test Site by injecting hot gas with Krypton-85 tracer to find out if future testing will not leak radioactive particles.
- After that NASA and DOE will go for approval of testing by higher-ups in 2015.
- If approved, full scale testing will be started at Nevada Test Site in late 2019.
- Flight technology demonstration mission is scheduled for 2023.

[image: timeline courtesy Stan Borowski]

Answer (score 7):

It was DoD, not NASA, but there was a post-NERVA nuclear rocket research program named [Project TIMBERWIND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Timberwind).

The summary of the project at its conclusion can be gleaned from this [report](https://web.archive.org/web/20130408131611/http://www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?AD=ADA305996).